# couldn't change active tabPage with button c#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a MetroTabControl named mtcNewExpTabControl with four pages(mtpSettings, mtpNewExp, mtpTempImages, mtpCompareImages).

I am starting New Experiment on mtpNewExp page and get image after clicking "StartExperiment" button. User can get many images. After completion of experiment, I add images to **imageList1.Images**. 
When I click on the mtpTempImages tabPage **mtcNewExpTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged** triggered and images are displayed with combobox named with imageList1.Images.Keys[i]. I can show many combobox and picturebox pairs on mtpTempImages.

On mtpTempImages there is also a **mtbCompareImages** button. User can check checkboxes next to the picturebox named same with checboxName. After checking all the checkboxes needed to compared, user will click on the "Compare Images" button.

I want to change active tabPage to mtpCompareImages without clicking on the tab. **mtbCompareImages** button should be enough for that. I can show images on mtpTempImages but I could not succeded that on mtpCompareImages tabpage. Active tabPage also do not change to mtpCompareImages tabPage. What should I do?

```
    List<MetroCheckBox> cbxTempImages = new List<MetroCheckBox>();
    List<MetroCheckBox> cbxCompareImages = new List<MetroCheckBox>();
    List<PictureBox> pbxTempImages = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> pbxCompareImages = new List<PictureBox>();

    private void mtbCompareImages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cbxTempImages.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (cbxTempImages[i].Checked == true)
            {
                imageListChecked.Images.Add(pbxTempImages[i].Name, pbxTempImages[i].Image);
            }
        }
        this.mtcNewExpTabControl.SelectedTab = mtpCompareImages;

    }

    private void mtcNewExpTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        if((MetroTabPage)this.mtcNewExpTabControl.SelectedTab == mtpTempImages)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageList1.Images.Count; i++)
            {
                cbxTempImages.Add(new MetroCheckBox());

                cbxTempImages[i].Name = imageList1.Images.Keys[i].ToString();
                cbxTempImages[i].Size = new Size(15, 15);
                cbxTempImages[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                cbxTempImages[i].Location = new Point(x, y);

                //PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
                pbxTempImages.Add(new PictureBox());
                pbxTempImages[i].Name = imageList1.Images.Keys[i].ToString();
                pbxTempImages[i].Image = imageList1.Images[i];
                pbxTempImages[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pbxTempImages[i].Location = new Point(x + 15, y);
                x += 120;
                if (x > this.pnlTempImages.Width - 120)
                {
                    x = 10; y += 100;
                }

                this.pnlTempImages.Controls.Add(cbxTempImages[i]);
                this.pnlTempImages.Controls.Add(pbxTempImages[i]);
            }

        }
        else if((MetroTabPage)this.mtcNewExpTabControl.SelectedTab ==  mtpCompareImages)
        {

            x = 10; y = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < imageListChecked.Images.Count; i++)
            {
                cbxCompareImages.Add(new MetroCheckBox());
                //MetroCheckBox cbxCI = new MetroCheckBox();
                cbxCompareImages[i].Name = imageListChecked.Images.Keys[i].ToString();
                cbxCompareImages[i].Size = new Size(15, 15);
                cbxCompareImages[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                cbxCompareImages[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
                //PictureBox picCI = new PictureBox();
                pbxCompareImages.Add(new PictureBox());
                pbxCompareImages[i].Name = imageListChecked.Images.Keys[i].ToString();
                pbxCompareImages[i].Image = imageListChecked.Images[i];
                pbxCompareImages[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pbxCompareImages[i].Location = new Point(x + 15, y);
                x += 120;
                if (x > this.pnlCompareImages.Width - 120)
                {
                    x = 10; y += 100;
                }

                this.pnlCompareImages.Controls.Add(cbxCompareImages[i]);
                this.pnlCompareImages.Controls.Add(pbxCompareImages[i]);

            }
        }
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Very hard to guess why you'd call InitializeComponent() in a tab control's SelectedIndexChanged event handler.  That of course also initializes the tab control :)  That certainly looks like "couldn't change active tab".  Adding controls every single time a tabpage is selected is also a gross bug.

Comment: Mistake was mine. Thank you @HansPassant